# Task.ContinueWith does not work with OnlyOnCanceled

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

In the reference book for Microsoft's 70-483 exam about using CancellationToken, the first way to cancel with signal is through throwing an exception, and then it introduces the second:

> Instead of catching the exception, you can also add a continuation
>   Task that executes only when the Task is canceled. In this Task, you
>   have access to the exception that was thrown, and you can choose to
>   handle it if that’s appropriate. Listing 1-44 shows what such a
>   continuation task would look like

Here is the List 1-44:

```
        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            t.Exception.Handle((e) => true);
            Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task");
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

And this is my full Main method code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        t.Exception.Handle((e) => true);
        Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

    Console.ReadLine();
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    task.Wait();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However, unlike what it is stated, when I press Enter, the exception (AggregationException) still thrown to the Main method at `task.Wait()` call. Moreover, if I remove that call, the second Task never runs (no exception is thrown). Is there anything I do wrong? Is it possible to handle the exception without using `try-catch`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To explicitly state the problem, your second continuation is not executing, but you think it should:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
    {                                                     //  THIS
        t.Exception.Handle((e) => true);                  //  ISN'T
        Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task");  //  EXECUTING
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

    Console.ReadLine();
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    task.Wait();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The second continuation is not executing because you must use `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in order to trigger it:

```
        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();  // <-- NOTICE
                Console.Write("*");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Continuation: " + t.Status);

            Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task");
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

// OUTPUT:
// ***
// From Continuation: Canceled
// You have canceled the task
```

The second continuation *was* called because the `task.Status` was `Canceled`.  This next snippet does not trigger the second continuation, because the `task.Status` is not set to `Canceled`:

```
        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Continuation: " + t.Status);

            Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task");
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

// OUTPUT:
// AggregationException
```

As stated, the second continuation was not called.  Let's force its execution by removing the `OnlyOnCanceled` clause:

```
        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Continuation: " + t.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("You have NOT canceled the task");

        });   // <-- OnlyOnCanceled is gone!

// OUTPUT:
// ***
// From Continuation: RanToCompletion
// You have NOT canceled the task
// (no AggregationException thrown)
```

Notice that even though `.Cancel()` was called, the `task.Status` from within the continuation is `RanToCompletion`.  Also notice no `AggregationException` is thrown.  This shows that **just calling `.Cancel()` from the token source doesn't set the task status to `Canceled`.**

---

When only `.Cancel()` is called and `.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is not called, the `AggregationException` is actually an indicator of successful task cancellation.  To quote the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If you are waiting on a `Task` that transitions to the `Canceled` state, a `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` exception (wrapped in an `AggregateException` exception) is thrown. Note that this exception indicates successful cancellation instead of a faulty situation. Therefore, the task's `Exception` property returns `null`.

Which leads me to the grand conclusion:

### Listing 1-44 is a [known error](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0790145374318).

Your `t.Exception...` line has been omitted from all of my code, because "*the task's `Exception` property returns `null`*" upon successful cancellation.  The line *should* have been omitted from Listing 1-44.  It looks like they were conflating the following two techniques:

1. The first snippet of my answer is a valid way to cancel a task.  The `OnlyOnCanceled` continuation is called and no exception is thrown.
2. The second snippet of my answer is also a valid way to cancel a task, but the `OnlyOnCanceled` continuation is NOT called and an AggregationException is thrown for you to handle at `Task.Wait()`

Disclaimer: both snippets are valid ways to cancel a task, but they probably have differences in behavior that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I've been wondering about this bizarre mechanism in the book for hours... Your detailed explanations were really helpful! I got the error due to the `t.Exception...` part.

Answer (score 2):

A task instance that is canceled with `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` will have the `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` state, not to the `TaskStatus.Canceled` state. So I think that you have to change the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled` to `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion`

You can check [Task Cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Here is a the sample code:

```
 CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    t.Exception.Handle((e) => true);
    Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

Console.ReadLine();
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

try
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + v.Message);
    }
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I also tried like this before, but strange thing is that, the second Task never runs. There is no "You have canceled the task" statement printed on the Console. On my console, only one **** line, and then "One or more errors occurred. A task was canceled.", then when I press Enter, the program ends.

Comment: A task instance that is canceled with **cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();** will have the  **TaskStatus.RanToCompletion** state, not to the **TaskStatus.Canceled** state. So I think that you have to change the **TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled** to **TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion**

Comment: Ok, then I think the code itself lost its purpose. You cannot know if it was really cancelled or finished. Wonder why Microsoft let this mistake through. Thank you very much. Please edit your answer, then I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true) {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Console.Write("*");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            //t.Exception.Handle((e) => true); //there is no exception
            Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task");
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

Comment: Uhm... I tried all 3 cases: use the same as your code, add only the Throw line, comment only the Handle line, but all 3 throw exceptions. Can you please test again and post your full working Main method?